# authentication in django back end

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

How exactly the django "remember me" functionality work in back-end?

Answer (score 0):

You set expiry session time to achieve `remember me` feature.

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # actual login code
        if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
        else:
            request.session.set_expiry(60 * 60 * 24 * 30) # one month validity
    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```